# Run Time Error '7'. Out of Memory when trying to run VBA code

Tags: vba, excel

Basically what the code does is, it looks for duplicate values in rows and transposes the corresponding values to columns. The code works perfectly for small amount of rows. The problem is I've a lot of spreadsheets with 600,000+ rows of data. Now when I select all the data and run the code it gives me "Run Time Error '7': Out of Memory" error.

The line the debugger highlights is:

```
ReDim Preserve xArr1(1 To UBound(xArr1, 1), 1 To xArr2(1) + t - 1)
```

And here is the whole VBA code:

```
Sub ConvertTable()
Update 20150113
Dim xArr1 As Variant
Dim xArr2 As Variant
Dim InputRng As Range, OutRng As Range
Dim xRows As Long
xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"
Set InputRng = Application.Selection
Set InputRng = Application.InputBox("Range :", xTitleId, InputRng.Address, Type:=8)
Set OutRng = Application.InputBox("Out put to (single cell):", xTitleId, Type:=8)
Set OutRng = OutRng.Range("A1")
xArr1 = InputRng.Value
t = UBound(xArr1, 2): xRows = 1
With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    .CompareMode = 1
    For i = 2 To UBound(xArr1, 1)
        If Not .exists(xArr1(i, 1)) Then
            xRows = xRows + 1: .Item(xArr1(i, 1)) = VBA.Array(xRows, t)
            For ii = 1 To t
                xArr1(xRows, ii) = xArr1(i, ii)
            Next
        Else
            xArr2 = .Item(xArr1(i, 1))
            If UBound(xArr1, 2) < xArr2(1) + t - 1 Then
                ReDim Preserve xArr1(1 To UBound(xArr1, 1), 1 To xArr2(1) + t - 1)
                For ii = 2 To t
                    xArr1(1, xArr2(1) + ii - 1) = xArr1(1, ii)
                Next
            End If
            For ii = 2 To t
                xArr1(xArr2(0), xArr2(1) + ii - 1) = xArr1(i, ii)
            Next
            xArr2(1) = xArr2(1) + t - 1: .Item(xArr1(i, 1)) = xArr2
        End If
    Next
End With
OutRng.Resize(xRows, UBound(xArr1, 2)).Value = xArr1
End Sub
```

Credit: I found the original VBA code from [here](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2538-excel-transpose-duplicate-row-to-columns.html#a1).

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Just read MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8k3cys2.aspx When you ReDim with preserve then you may only change the last dimension (not the first one).

Comment: You may want to look at [this too](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7817427/excel-2007-vba-array-size-limit)

Comment: @Sgdva Thank you very much for the link. I installed excel 64 bit and it works perfectly now.

Comment: If it helped please, mark answer accepted :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Solution:***

Install Excel 64 bits, Excel 32 bits can't handle that amount of memory

**Disclaimer**

While [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7817427/excel-2007-vba-array-size-limit) basically has the same memory problem, it may be confusing what the real solution is (the one provided here). If you would like to discuss either or not this answer should be deleted, please comment below before down voting.