# Excel transpose 2D array - Out of memory issue

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, transpose

I have a VBA macro, where I want to write out an array to an Excel sheet.
I'm getting an "Out of memory" runtime error on some machines. I can run it easily on my development PC, but my client has issues with it.

Here I define my **Values** array:

```
Dim Values()
Dim idx As Long
idx = 0
```

Then I have a for cycle where I dynamically redim the array, and add my values to it:

```
for cycle...
    ReDim Preserve Values(16, 0 To idx)
    Values(0, idx) = "some text"
    Values(1, idx) = "some other text"
    ....
    Values(15, idx) = "last values for this row"
    idx = idx + 1
next
```

Then here is where my code fails:

```
With ws
    .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1+ idx - 1, 16)).value = TransP(Values)
End With
```

Here's the **TransP** transposing function:

```
Public Function TransP(var As Variant) As Variant
    Dim outP() As Variant, i As Long, j As Long
    ReDim outP(LBound(var, 2) To UBound(var, 2), LBound(var, 1) To UBound(var, 1))
    For i = LBound(outP) To UBound(outP)
      For j = LBound(var) To UBound(var)
        outP(i, j) = var(j, i)
      Next
    Next
    TransP = outP
End Function
```

As I said, I can run the macro, and get something like 108770 rows. The same 108770 rows don't work on my clients PC.

I expect that the TransP function gives up on his PC, so should I split up the array into multiple smaller chunks, and write them 1 by 1?
Or my data model is not good?

Comment: Just checking: your client doesn't use MS Excel 2003?

Comment: Note, they use Excel 2013 and up.

Comment: What is `idxUA`?

Comment: @Tom sorry for that, I actually made some small corrections to the code when I posted it, and I renamed idxUA to idx here on stackoverflow. I didn't notice that I didn't change it in all places. I corrected the code example now.

Comment: @Laureant That's fine - I was just wondering whether `idxUA` could be 0 which could cause an error. I'd also try and avoid using `Values` as a variable name - it is very close to actual syntax and could lead to erroneous mistype errors.

Answer (score 2):

Your method of appending elements to `Values` is inefficient because every time an element is added a new array is created and the values of the existing one copied to it. During this time twice the memory is in use, and if a large array is copied in this way multiple times in quick succession only heaven can know what demands are put on the RAM management.

The better way is to dimension the array larger than will be required (once), count the number of elements written to it and use `Redim Preserve` to reduce its size (once) when you are done.

Comment: The problem with that is that in the beginning I have no idea how big the array will be.

Comment: Surely you will be able to estimate 100,000 or 1 million. If even that isn't possible consider expanding the array only after the million has been reached, by another million, etc. Compare this effort with that of copying a million elements a million times. A blank element takes up very little memory.

Comment: Just `ReDim` the array to the number of rows your have in your `For` loop and use a counter for the array position. Then after the `For` loop `ReDim Preserve` the array to the value of your counter

Comment: @Tom there's a complex object hierarchy, so there's not just ONE for loop. There are multiple ones. I just wanted to get the code examples as basic as possible. That's why I can't specify the exact (or even an estimate) number of how many rows I'll have.

Comment: @Variatus and what would happen if I estimate 1 million? Wouldn't it cause the same memory error if I Redim to 1 million rows?

Comment: @Laureant - Well then you know your loop criteria. Add the max of each together before starting. In terms of maximum size of an array take a look at this answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7817805/3042759)

Comment: @Laureant Please don't forget the issue: Your array has reach 1000 elements. To add one element, you create a new array with 1001 elements. Now you copy 1000 elements from the old to the new. When this is done the old array's RAM space should be released. But what happens if a third array is created before the copying from the first has finished? We don't know if this is what's happening but if it does it looks acrobatic. The point is creation of new arrays in quick succession. This wouldn't occur if expansion only takes place every 1mn elements.

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys, this might be a good option to include in the update to the code, but this is not why the code fails.I mentioned in my original post, that the code fails at the part where the Excel range is populated with the data. It could also be that the TransP function is causing the issue.
Do you think that it could fail, because all the ReDim-ing is still locked in the memory?

Comment: That is the presumption on which I have built my reply.

Answer (score 2):

You could also create a loop to write your output array row by row, it will take more time but you will most likely don't get out of memory error.

In the past when I've got out of memory issues with an arrays I just tried to perform actions using regular excel commands, in this case you could just copy range and than paste transposed values:

```
.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's the TransP function, since that is already handling everything in a loop. I experienced the same sort of issue and there this error occured when I tried to transfer a large multidimensional array to a range.

My solution was to create a loop and do about a 1000 rows each time, but that depends on the clients pc I guess with how many rows you can do.

To take into account that `var` will not end on a certain step size, you could do a while loop:

```
i = 0
with ws
Do while i < Ubound(var)
   max = application.worksheetfunction.max(1000,Ubound(var) - i) 'At some point, you could have less than 1000 left
  .range(.cells(i+1,1), .cells(i+max)) = TransP(var,i,max)
  i = i + 1000
Loop
```

In TransP you now use the lower- and upperbound of `var`, but if you add two variables from the loop, you can use them to only take a piece of the array.

Comment: This seems like a good candidate...how would I split the large array into smaller ones, without going through the elements and copying them one-by-one?

Comment: I changed the answer to include a way of doing it, because it was too messy in a comment.

Comment: How would I rewrite the TransP function to accept the additional two parameters?

Comment: You create the `outP` array based on the lowerbound and upperbound of `var`. You could instead use the values from `i` and `max` from the main function.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this might be due to you not specifying the dimension in your `TransP` function. You are also defining your loops with both arrays. You've sized them identically (although with the dimensions switched) - Just use the same one to define your `For` loop

```
Public Function TransP(var As Variant) As Variant
    Dim outP() As Variant, i As Long, j As Long
    ReDim outP(LBound(var, 2) To UBound(var, 2), LBound(var, 1) To UBound(var, 1))
    For i = LBound(outP, 1) To UBound(outP, 1)
      For j = LBound(outP, 2) To UBound(outP, 2)
        outP(i, j) = var(j, i)
      Next
    Next
    TransP = outP
End Function
```